# Node.js how to get cookies from a website

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I need to take all the cookies from a particular website.
Currently I check what's in the header `set-cookie` and do some processing with it.
The code I use is as follows:

```
function getCookies(hostname) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        https.request(hostname,  function(res) {
            resolve(res.headers['set-cookie'])
        }).end()
    })
}
```

Then if a do: `const cookies = await getCookies('...')` i got all the cookies.

For most websites, cookies are actually present in the set-cookie header and I can process them.

However, I have come across some sites (whose hostname I take) that have cookies in the browser but **no** `set-cookie` header. From the browser console I use the `document.cookie` method to access the cookies, but I can't see where they are stored.
The problem with the `document.cookie` is that it only returns the names of the cookies present and not all their values (such as domain, expiry date etc.).

**Is there another way in Node.js to get all the cookies of a website given its url?** Where are these cookies stored that I can't find in the `set-cookie` header?

Comment: These cookies are created by JS in the browser, which means you need to use puppeteer or a similar solution to get them (because you need to actually open the website instead of just loading its index.html)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG i'm actually using this script in a lighthouse Audit so i can send JS commands inside the DOM of the page i am inspecting.
If window.document is not working because is not giving back all the cookie information what kind of command can i use in the browser console in order to get all the cookie informations? Such like expiration date, domain etc..?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can somehow intercept the website scripts' setting of `document.cookie` using a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)? Not sure

Comment: The problem is that if i use `document.cookie` it returns all the cookie but only the names. I need also their values.
Is there one other command to call on document in order to get also the cookie information?

Comment: Not that I know of, which is why I suggested to intercept the script doing `document.cookie = x;`